# How to Convert date into String format to Date format in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to convert this ("2019-09-09"(yyyy-MM-dd)) string into date format. I am using `DateTime.ParseExact` method, but it is not giving me the expected output.

```
string transactionDateFrom = "2019-09-09";
var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var c = DateTime.ParseExact(transactionDateFrom, "yyyy-MM-dd", provider);
```

But it shows output as (09/09/2019 12:12Am) I just need format like (yyyy-MM-dd) and it must be date format not string.

Comment: What you mean by saying _not giving me expected output_ ? You have the string representation of a date and you want to parse this, in order to create a `DateTime` representation of this date. That you have tried is sufficient for that purpose. If you need from the `DateTime` to get the string representation of the DateTime object you have created, you should define format of the output, by passing it as an argument to the `ToString` method. e.g. `c.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your result. I get date with no time.What are you using to view the value of `c`

Comment: Furthermore, as also @PeterSmith pointed out, from the code you have shared, 09/09/2019 12:12Am can not be reproduced. So if you have any other code, please share it. Thanks

Comment: the above code works fine, the issue is going to be the line of code that will output / display your `datetime` variable, where you would need to specify the format. So rather share with us the code part that outputs this datetime.

Comment: `DateTime` does not have a format.  When you come to display it you need to define the format you want by using `dateTime.ToString(format)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also provide format for ToString or whenever you use that, since right now you only use it for parsing.

You may also just edit the culture the following way:

```cs
CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use `DateTime.TryParseExact` or use `DateTime.TryParse` specifying the appropriate CultureInfo. 
(For E.g., the culture of the user.)

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` method overloads and you can specify exact format and proper (that uses / as a DateSeparator) culture information.

Also be aware that the Difference between M and MM specifiers.
For single digit month numbers, MM specifier will generate month number with leading zero (like 09) but M specifier won't.

```
string strDate = "2019-09-28";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string Format = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**OR**

```
string strDate = "2019-9-28";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "yyyy-M-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string Format = date.ToString("yyyy-M-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```